# Cucumber feature not reporting a NoMethod Error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cucumber

```
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
  * cucumber (1.3.19)
  * cucumber-rails (1.4.2)
  * declarative_authorization (0.5.7)
  * devise (3.5.1)
  * devise_security_extension (0.9.2)
  * rails (4.2.1)
```

I am migrating a project from RoR-3.2 to RoR-4.2 one model/controller at a time.  I have set up a 'clean' rails project to receive the existing code in steps and am revising the Cucumber features and steps as I go.  I have a situation where a scenario is passing but when the controller exercised in that scenario is run in development then the following error is raised:

```
 NoMethodError in UsersController#create 
 undefined method `hll_normalise' for "superuser":String 

Extracted source (around line #21): 

19  def rolename=(name) 
20    # hll_normalise is a local extension of class  String.
21    write_attribute(:rolename, name.hll_normalise)
22  end
20

Rails.root:
/home/byrnejb/Projects/Software/theHeart/code/hll_th_main
Application 
Trace <http://localhost:3000/users#> | Framework Trace 
<http://localhost:3000/users#> | Full Trace

<http://localhost:3000/users#> app/models/role.rb:21:in 
`rolename=' <http://localhost:3000/users#>
app/models/role.rb:33:in 

`add_required_roles' <http://localhost:3000/users#>
app/models/user.rb:34:in `bootstrap' <http://localhost:3000/users#>
libexec/bundle/lib/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:432:in

`block in make_lambda' <http://localhost:3000/users#>
libexec/bundle/lib/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:164:in

`call' <http://localhost:3000/users#>
libexec/bundle/lib/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:164:in

`block in halting' <http://localhost:3000/users#>
libexec/bundle/lib/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in 

`call' <http://localhost:3000/users#>
 libexec/bundle/lib/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in

`block in call' <http://localhost:3000/users#>
libexec/bundle/lib/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in

`each' <http://localhost:3000/users#> . . .
```

I believe that I know what is causing the underlying error, a missing custom library extension to class STRING, and how to repair it.  Before I do so I wish to uncover why this error is not causing the scenario to fail during the Cucumber run.

The code that is failing is called in an associated model and is exercised when a User is created.  So it should trigger a failure in the Cucumber run.  But it does not.  I have three rescue clauses in the user code base present and none fail to re-raise any caught errors.